# learning swift by GuidedTour

Tags: swift-playground

in this example of GuidedTour of Swift by

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil 
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"    
var greeting = "Hello!"

if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(   name)"
}
```

I can not do this experiment, because of error

Change `optionalName` to `nil`. What greeting do you get? Add an `else` clause that sets a different greeting if `optionalName` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create new playground and enter exactly the same code you posted, it works. Can you post complete code ?

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
   greeting = "Hello, \(   name)"
}
```

Only thing which is different, seems that you forgot to import Foundation framework:

```
import Foundation
```

Comment: could you please send me result of changes in that experiment?

Comment: No problem, here is the playground: http://www.tagtaxa.com/download/playground.zip

Comment: I mean result of this: Change optionalName to nil. What greeting do you get? Add an else clause that sets a different greeting if optionalName is nil.

swift

Comment: Oh, sorry, if you change optionalName to nil you won't get greeting because optional unwrapping won't succeed. Look the example: http://www.tagtaxa.com/download/playground2.zip

Answer (score 0):

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
print(optionalString == nil)



var optionalName: String? = nil
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}else{
    greeting = "Hello Max"
}
greeting
```